# Scheduled functions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In objective-c, how can I make something like "well, I want you to run X function in 2.5 seconds".

I used a game development objective-c framework called Cocos2d, and it has a function that lets me schedule (and unschedule) functions, but I am not using Cocos2d for this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your app is based around NSRunLoop (which pretty much all of them are), you can use NSObject's [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a) or [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, probably the simplest is using `performSelector:`, like:

```
[obj performSelector:@selector(scheduledMethod) 
          withObject: paramOrNil 
          afterDelay:2.5];
```

Note that unlike the cocos2d scheduler, the `NSObject` variant does not pass your method the actual amount of elapsed time, so you cannot rely on it for anything requiring a high degree of precision or accuracy (unless you add your own code for computing the actual elapsed time between scheduling and invocation).

The [reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) provides some additional discussion.

Comment: Note that NSTimer can be used as well and has some definite advantages.